# Nested Attributes - Cocoon Gem - form_for “First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty” - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

This is an oldie but goldie, therefore I am really sorry for asking, but after checking 10+ posts with the similar errors, I still had no luck so far.

Attempting to use a "form for" to get nested forms to work with the help of the Cocoon gem.

Though I am getting the "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error.

Here is the **_text_form partial.html.erb :**

```
<%= form_for(@text, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Enter Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :publication, placeholder: "Enter Publication" %>
  <%= f.text_field :author, placeholder: "Enter Author" %>
  <%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: "Enter Url" %> 
 </div>
 <div>
  <h3>Quotes:</h3>
  <div id="quotes">
    <%= f.fields_for :quotes do |quote| %>
      <%= render 'shared/quote_fields', f: quote %>
    <% end %>

   <div class="links">
     <%= link_to_add_association 'add quote', f, :quotes, class: "btn btn-default" %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the **_quotes_fields.html.erb partial**:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
 <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new quote..." %>
 <span class="picture">
  <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
 </span>
 <%= link_to_remove_association "remove quote", f, class: "btn btn-default" %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#quote_picture').bind('change', function() {
   var size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
   if (size_in_megabytes > 2) {
     alert('Maximum file size is 2MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
   }
  });
</script>
```

This is the **texts_controller.rb**:

```
class TextsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy
 before_action :find_text, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]



 def show
 end

 def new
  @text = current_user.texts.build
 end

 def create
  @text = current_user.texts.build(text_params)
  if @text.save
   flash[:success] = "Text created!"
   redirect_to root_url
  else
   render 'static_pages/home'
  end
 end


 def edit
 end

 def update
  if @text.update(text_params)
   redirect_to @text
  else
  render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @text.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Text deleted"
  redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
 end

private

 def text_params
  params.require(:text).permit(:url, :title, :coverimage,
                              :publication, :author, :summary, quotes_attributes: [:id, :content, :picture, :_destroy])
 end

 def find_text
    @text = Text.find(params[:id])
 end

 def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
 end

end
```

Sorry upfront, if there are any easy horrifying newbie mistakes and thanks so much for helping out.

**Update:**
The _text_form partial is rendered in ../static_pages/home.html.erb

**Update 2:**
This is the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 get 'password_resets/new'

 get 'password_resets/edit'

 get 'sessions/new'

 root           'static_pages#home'
 get 'help'  => 'static_pages#help'
 get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
 get 'signup' => 'users#new'
 get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
 post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
 delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
 resources :users do
  member do
   get :following, :followers
  end
 end
 resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
 resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
 resources :quotes, only: [:create, :destroy]
 resources :texts, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
 resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
 end
```

Comment: where do you render `_text_form partial.html.erb `

Comment: I am rendering it in /static_pages/home.html.erb

Comment: what is your action to render home.hmtl.erb? please show your routes.

Comment: Thanh, thanks so much for looking into it. Added the routes file above.

Comment: ok, so you should go to static pages controller, add this code: @text = current_user.texts.build in home action.

Comment: That's it! Thanh, you are the man!  I totally missed it to update the static pages controller. Thanks so much. Really appreciated! Made my day.

Comment: ok @YvonC I add it as answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because @text is not defined yet, so you just need to define it in action which you will render your partial, in this case is your home action in your static pages controller.